# All Scala futures completed

Tags: scala, future

I have an akka actor in which I have several futures in scala that do just some extra work and save the computation into the shared variable. After the main work is done, I want to wait for these 'extra' futures and reply with an answer. The simple code is like this:

```
....
val replyTo = sender()
var informationCollector = InformationCollector()
val mainFuture: Future[GetMainInformation] = ...
val aFuture: Future[GetExtraInformationA] =...
val bFuture: Future[GetExtraInformationB] =...
val cFuture: Future[GetExtraInformationC] =...

// now I want all the futures to write their result
// and save it into the informationCollector and then
// after all have executed, reply back to Sender all the collected Data.
```

With this approach, I have 2 issues. I am not sure that acessing the InformationCollector is safe within the onSuccess calls of the futures and I also would like to make this easily extensible (so other collectors may be easily added).

Until now, I came up with this solution, however I am not sure it is correct

```
// IMPORTANT: firstly add map for all of the extraInfoFutures to add that information into collector
// this will create aFutureMapped, bFutureMapped, cFutureMapped
roomFuture onComplete {
      case Success(mainInfo: GetMainInformation) => {
           informationCollector = informationCollector.copy(mainInformation=mainInfo)
           Future.sequence(List(aFutureMapped,bFutureMapped,cFutureMapped)) onComplete { _ =>
               replyTo ! informationCollector
           }

      }
}
```

Any help highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I fully understood your question but I can provide an answer at least to the first issue.

It is potentially unsafe to access mutable state in `onComplete`. Actually it voids the whole purpose of the actor. If you access the mutable state you should always do it through the mailbox of the actor e.g. `self ! ModifyState(newValue)`.

The problem here is that the `onComplete` method is not in the same thread with the actor causing a situation where potentially two threads are concurrently modifying same data and thus mutating the state has all the same problems that there is generally in concurrent mutation of state (race condition etc).

For the second issue I would just collect the values from the different types of extra Futures through `self ! TypeAExtraValue(someValue)` and then send the collector (e.g. `TypeAInfoCollector`) after receiving all the extra values. When used correctly actors remove this problem since they process only one message at a time.

The code could look something like this:

```
val extraInfoFuture = getExtraInfo()
val infoCollector = new Collector()

extraInfoFuture onComplete {
  case Success(extraInfo) => self ! ExtraInfo(extraInfo) 
}

...

def receive = {
  case ExtraInfo(info) => {
    infoCollector.collect(info)
    if(infoCollector.collectedAll) sender() ! infoCollector
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello jubis, thanks for the answer. You are correct with multiple onComplete threads accessing the same variable. However is that an issue even if the variable is only in the scope of receive() method (it is not an attribute of the whole actor class) and there is only one onComplete? I still have multiple onCompletes accessing that variable, so this will be an issue still, though.

Comment: Of course you could try to prevent the problems using scope. However you might accidentally move the variable to another place some day and forget about the purpose of the scope.

Using only one `onComplete` is still unsafe: the `onComplete` would still be in another thread than the actor itself and thus there is two thread modifying the state.

Comment: Think it like it would be Swing :) (you can access the UI only in the UI thread)

Comment: but what I do is actually I initialize the variable in the receive() method before the described future is even created. After the variable is initialized, future is created, then the future is the only place accessing that variable afterwards, so I don't think this may be a problem. Or do you see a problem here?

Comment: That seems less risky - there isn't a situation where you would access the same variable from multiple threads. However this solution doesn't scale (second future would create the risk) and it still has the risk that you change your code and access the same variable elsewhere **inside the receive**.

Comment: Actually, in your situation I would create the futures outside the actor and simply pass the results to the factor (`dataFuture onSuccess (collector ! Data(_))`). This is because actor is at its best when it is used only as a container for the mutable state in concurrent environment.

Comment: I think I get your point, thank you very much for the answers.